# Extracting an image in Photoshop CS6

Tags: cs6, transparency

In Photoshop 6 there was a menu item to extract an image.  Essentially, it would allow you to create a transparent image so that you could apply Styles to the image.

In Photoshop CS6 I've found a tutorial on making a mask by using the Quick Selection tool.  However, the tutorial wasn't really geared towards my outcome, so now all I have is a mask.  And anytime I try to apply a Style to it, it just styles my entire image.

How do I create a transparent image so that I can add styles?  I'm using CS6 on a Win2K computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gah.  OK, hopefully this helps someone.  I just looked at:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/68312/photoshop-cs6-transparency-issue

and realized I need to go to Select -> Inverse and then Edit -> Cut to cut the background out.  After that I got the results I was hoping for.